# Cannot install. ipa in iOS real device with appium

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, appium, appium-ios

I am currently not able to install the `.ipa` file with appium.

I am able to install with `ideviceinstaller` manually with the command `ideviceinstaller -i abc.ipa`

but in appium, when I run my cucumber tests, I get the following error, when i tries to install,

```
 Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command failed: 
 ideviceinstaller -u udid -i 
 /var/folders/58/bqk7r15x7hv_l35vll1hg5_w0000gp/T/2017311-19876-
 1upzlv/Payload/abc.app
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:202:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

My `env.rb` file is

```
 require "appium_lib"

 def caps
  {
  caps:{ deviceName: "iPhone",
         platformName: "iOS",
         app: (File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "abc.ipa")),
         bundleId: "com.abc.abc",
         newCommandTimeout: "3600",
         appium_lib: { wait: 20,
                       debug: false
            }
       }
   }
  end


 def server_url
  'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub'
 end

 Appium::Driver.new(caps)   
 Appium.promote_appium_methods Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears like the Appium cannot handle the `'` in the path of the .app and has been acknowledged by the appium team for the fix in `iOS` in 1.5.3 version.